# How to find all assets on a webpage using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'd like to use puppeteer to scour a page and return all available assets including images, pdfs, anything embeddable, etc.

For our purposes here, let's roll simply with images. `img` tag has an `src` property but what about images loaded through CSS rules? Is there a way to see the totality of the assets loaded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to [listen on the event](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-request) `requestfinished`

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

page.on('requestfinished', (request) => {
    console.log(request.url())
});

await page.goto('http://www.wildesoft.net/');
await page.waitFor(5000);

await browser.close();
```

This will log to the console all resources received e.g.

[image: Screen grab of result]